# Java Inheritance implemented with Decorator pattern

Tags: java, inheritance, decorator

Is it right to think that under the hoods java inheritance
is implemented using **Decorator Pattern** ?
In my mind inheritance and Decorator Pattern look very similar almost
indistinguishable.

EDIT:
I mean, let `A` be a subclass of `B`,we can say that in `A` the keyword `super`always  refers to the object of type `A` we are "decorating".

Thanks

Comment: I think it would be more accurate to say the `Decorator Pattern` is implemented using `Inheritance`

Comment: Seems a lot more like an [inheritance pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) than a decorator pattern to me.

Comment: @chancea Not necessarily. According to wikipedia, the decorator pattern CAN use inheritance.

Comment: I think inheritance is a concept that applies to the type system of a programming language; whereas the decorator pattern does not necessarily make statements regarding the type system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `inheritance` and `decorator pattern` have in common is the fact that they both allow you to change how an object behaves. Also, to be more precise,   `decorator pattern` is implemented by the concept of `inheritance`.

But the difference:

1.`Decorator pattern` makes run-time object changes easier:

2.`Decorator Pattern` makes multiple behavior modifications easier

3.`Decorator pattern` is not necessary in non-dynamic situations

Answer (score 0):

I doubt Java implements inheritance under the hood using the Decorator pattern. Relationships between base classes and their extensions are fixed at compile time, whereas relationships between decorators and the objects they decorate can change at run time.